# how to store a json object react native

Tags: json, react-native, asyncstorage

```
 {
"code": 200,
"message": "User Login successfully",
"data": {
    "_id": "5da6ebf323410526a25162d2",
    "name": "abcd",
    "email": "abcd@example.com",
    "preferences": {
        "email": 1,
        "feed": 1,
    },
    "notification_status": "On",
    "updated_at": "2020-12-11 05:36:02",
    "created_at": "2020-10-16 10:07:47",
    "group_ids": [],
    "roles": [
        {
            "_id": "5d96e202c01249370e25b7c9",
            "name": "abcd",
            "guard_name": "web",
            "member_ids": [
                "5da81af673176e067f22545a"

            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

want to store the json object "data" in an object and retrieve the valus from "data" whenever require. 
how to do?

Comment: Hello @user12371061, It is very simple to store json object in any variable.
You just need to write `data = {whatever your json data}`

Comment: .then((response) => response.json())
             .then((responseJson) => {                    
                if(responseJson.code == 200){
                    //alert(responseJson.message);
                    alert(this.retrieveData());
                    this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
                }else{
                    alert("Wrong login details");
                }
                
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });

Comment: @user12371061 what do you mean by whenever require? all over the app or only in this component?

Comment: @Horst all over the app

Answer (score 2):

You can store and retrieve data using AsyncStorage:-

```
const data = {
"code": 200,
"message": "User Login successfully",
 "data": {
"_id": "5da6ebf323410526a25162d2",
"name": "abcd",
"email": "abcd@example.com",
"preferences": {
    "email": 1,
    "feed": 1,
},
"notification_status": "On",
"updated_at": "2020-12-11 05:36:02",
"created_at": "2020-10-16 10:07:47",
"group_ids": [],
"roles": [
    {
        "_id": "5d96e202c01249370e25b7c9",
        "name": "abcd",
        "guard_name": "web",
        "member_ids": [
            "5da81af673176e067f22545a"

        ]
    }
]
}
}

// storing data in to local storage
AsyncStorage.setItem("dataKey", JSON.stringify(data))

// retrieving data whenever you need from local storage
AsyncStorage.getItem("dataKey").then(data => {
  if(data){
     let ourData = JSON.parse(data)
     console.log("ourData >>>>> ",ourData)
  }
}).catch(err => console.log("error >>>>> ",err))
```

Answer (score 1):

For data storing, I suggest you to utilize [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) (A predictable state container for JavaScript apps.) in ReactNative.

You may not want to store everything on AsyncStroage as it persists data on your device, hence choose to store your data wisely on Redux / AsyncStorage.

Long story short, below shows the concept of Redux. ([Img Source from Tutorial Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/redux/redux_data_flow.htm))

[image]

---

### Brief explanation:## (in sequence)

***VIEW***

1. On UI View, user tapped on a button (Say that I wan to get my remaining wallet value)

***ACTION***

2. Action fired with a Action Key (each action has it's own specific key, which you have to define) `this.props.getWalletValue()`
3. Method getWalletValue triggered, response comes back from API.

***DISPATCH***

4. Dispatch response from API. Here, it could be success/failed state.
5. Dispatch pass the type of dispatch to Reducer

***REDUCER & STORE & STATE***

6. Reducer then return the value from API response to STORE and keep in STATE

***VIEW***

7. Developer can now get the response from Redux via method `mapStateToProps` to get desired result. These results are coming from STORE.

---